# Trouble on getting xpath from Science Magazine, it returns a list with no elements

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

The page I am currently working on can be accessed by doi.org this is the code of the article: 10.1126/science.aaa1442

Anyway, I am trying to extract what is written in between the address tag, 
I used the following xpath expression

//li[@class='aff']

The html is as follows:

```
<li class="aff">
   <a id="aff-1" name="aff-1"></a>
   <address>
     <sup>1</sup>
     "Materials Science Division, Argonne National Laboratory, Lemont, 
      IL 60439, USA"
   </address>
</li>
```

What I got is the output: 
['', '', '', '', '', '']

I tried to extend the xpath including //li[@class='aff']/address and made some experiments with absolute paths copied from google chrome developer tool, which gave me the result ['']

The xpath is passed to this function I coded. It has been working in other cases, but not with this one:

```
def inspectElement(self,exp,atr=None): 

    def _init_(self,exp,atr):
        self.exp = exp
        self.atr = atr

    thread = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,(" %s" % exp))

    xArray = [] 

    for t in thread:
        if atr == 0:
            xThread = t.get_attribute('id')
        elif atr == 1:                
            xThread = t.get_attribute('href')
        else:
             xThread = t.text         
        xArray.append(xThread)  

    return xArray
```

I would like to get all the 6 elements currently empty in my list.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi powerPixie! So you use `//li[@class='aff']` to get some elements, what is your selenium code to extract the text that is not working properly?

Comment: Thank you for answering so fast. I've just edited to include the function that I use to get the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`//li[@class='aff']/address` Is what you should be using and should give you 6 elements. I've tested this locally and you might need to step through your code to see if there is some other issue here causing you to only get 1 result.

The other problem is that `<sup>` gets in the way of `t.text` returning anything. What you need to do instead is some version of:

`xThread = t.get_attribute('innerText')`

In this case you could add another option to your function and have something like this:

```
elif atr == 2:                
    xThread = t.get_attribute('innerText')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting any problem with either one of your expressions, but try

```
/li[@class='aff']/address/normalize-space()
```

Comment: Thank you for answering so fast.
It says:  Given xpath expression " //li[@class='aff']/address/normalize-space()" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.
I guess it has do to with the function I am using to extrat the text element from the xpath. I added the code in my original post. Function's name is inspectElement

Comment: @powerPixie - I don't know what to say; I tried it on two different xpath online testers (https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html and http://xpather.com/) and    they both gave the address as the output... Maybe try it with `text()` instead of `normalize-space()` and see if that's accepted.

Comment: The expression with `/normalize-space()` requires XPath 2.0 -- Selenium, shockingly, still only supports XPath 1.0.

Comment: @MichaelKay - Shockingly, indeed! Selenium, lxml, etc. - I really don't get it :(